# Problema en codigo

Tags: python

Realice este codigo para poder mostrar en pantalla si el numero es de 4,3,2 o un digito, mostrar cada digito y decir si el numero es positivo o negativo. No me arroja ningun error pero cuando compilo y quiero ingresar un numero menor a 4 digitos no cumple con la funcion deseada.

```
num=int(input('Ingrese un numero '))

if num >= 1000:
   print('El numero ingresado es de 4 digitos')
if num >= 100 and num <= 999 and num <= -100 and num >= -999:
   if num < 0:
      print('El numero ingresado es negativo')
   d1=num/100
   d2=num%100/10
   d3=num%100%10
   print('El numero ingresado es de 3 digitos')
   print(d1)
   print(d2)
   print(d3)
if num >=10 and num <= 99 and num <=-10 and num >= -99:
   if num < 0:
      print('El numero ingresado es negativo')
   d1=num/10
   d2=num%10
   print('El numero ingresado es de 2 digitos')
   print(d1)
   print(d2)

if num >=1 and num <= 9 and num <=-1 and num >= -9:
  if num < 0:
     print('El numero ingresado es negativo')
  print('El numero ingresado es de 1 digito')
  print(num)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando `and` en lugar de `or` en las comparaciones de rango como

```
if num >= 100 and num <= 999 and num <= -100 and num >= -999:
```

Aqui quieres saber si el número está entre 100 y 999 **o** entre -100 y -999. La forma correcta de escribirlo es:

```
if num >= 100 and num <= 999 or num <= -100 and num >= -999:
```

Lo mismo con las otras comparaciones.

También puedes simplificarlas:

```
if 100 <= num <= 999 or -999 <= num <= -100:
```

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Estas haciendo demasiadas cosas innecesarias, solo necesitas un `if` y listo

```py
num = input("ingrese un numero: ")

if int(num)<0:
    print("El numero es negativo")
    cant_cifras = len(num)-1
else:
    cant_cifras = len(num)
print(f"el numero es de {cant_cifras} digitos")
print('\n'.join(list(num)))#imprimimos cada digito
```

Con la funcion `len` sabes el tamaño del numero (en formato string) lo que vendría a ser el kumero de cifras o dígitos que tiene el número ingresado y con el `if` solo comprobamos que sea negativo. Lo bueno es que esto funciona para numeros de n dígitos

Comment: gracias panita, la verdad aun desconozco mucho de lo que pusiste ahi pero de todas formas gracias